# Controlled experiment with binary outcome variable

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, repeated-measures

I have data from an experiment where students were tested on multiple words for the correct pronunciation of a specific linguistic phenomena.

The experiment was done with a control and experimental group, and all students were tested prior to a specific instruction and at the
end of the experiments (roughly 8 weeks later).

```
> head(act1)
  studentid groupid itemid test type result
1        1B       B      1    0    1      0
2        5B       B      1    0    1      1
3        6B       B      1    0    1      1
4        8B       B      1    0    1      0
5       11B       B      1    0    1      1
6       15B       B      1    0    1      1

> levels(act1$groupid)
[1] "B" "D"
```

D is the experimental group while B is the control group.

First, I want to test the hypothesis that the experimental group has had a significant improvement in the production of the studied linguistic phenomena.

I ran McNemar's test on each group individually:

```
> act1wide <- reshape(act1, idvar=c("studentid","groupid","itemid","type"), timevar=c("test"), v.names=c("result"), direction="wide")
> act1wideb <- subset(act1wide, groupid=='B')
> act1wided <- subset(act1wide, groupid=='D')
> mcnemar.test(act1wideb$result.0, act1wideb$result.1)

    McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction

data:  act1wideb$result.0 and act1wideb$result.1 
McNemar's chi-squared = 0.0556, df = 1, p-value = 0.8137

> mcnemar.test(act1wided$result.0, act1wided$result.1)

    McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction

data:  act1wided$result.0 and act1wided$result.1 
McNemar's chi-squared = 9.0312, df = 1, p-value = 0.002654
```

This seems to show that group 'B' did not improve while group 'D' did.

**Questions:**

- Is this a valid test?
- How can I have a more meaningful test that would compare group data at the same time?
- The factor *type* has three levels. How can I break down the analysis to get specific information by type?

I am a bit of a stats noob so I greatly appreciate detailed explanations on how to make sense of my data.